# Запустить pip install

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Есть ли возможность запустить `pip install` из скрипта на python? Разумеется, я не хочу использовать обращение к ядру ОС.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15950647/7485582 https://stackoverflow.com/a/50255019/7485582

Comment: @КириллМалышев Окей, ну то же самое. Хочется без обращения к ядру ОС

Comment: @КириллМалышев вторую ссылку видел и там сыпется `deprecated`